# Convergence of maximum of random variables converging to zero

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Suppose that for a sample of identically distributed but non-independent uniformly bounded non-negative random variables we can show that $X_i = O_P(b_n)$ with $b_n$ a deterministic sequence converging to zero. Would it be possible to say something about the maximum of these random variables, namely $Y_n = \max_{i \leq n} X_i$? Intuitively one would expect that $Y_n = O_P(b_n)$ but with such things the devil is always in the details. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question...  (1) you mean $X_n = O_P(b_n)$, not $X_i = O_P(b_n)$, right?  (2) My understanding is that $O_P(.)$ means $X_n/b_n$ is bounded (probabilistically, for large $n$).  However you also said $X_n$ are identically distributed.  So how can they be bounded to a sequence $b_n \rightarrow 0$?  Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: It is implied that the $X_i$s tend to zero at a rate faster than equal to $b_n$, this is pretty standard notation.

Comment: ok thanks for clarifying, but still, if $X_i$ are identically distributed, how can they also tend to zero (unless they are all zero to begin with)?  also, if $X_i \rightarrow 0$, then $Y_n$ would be dominated by the initial $X_i$ values, e.g. if the sequence achieves max at $i=5$ then $Y_n = X_5 \forall n \ge 5$, and so $Y_n$ will certainly not tend to 0.

Comment: There is no contradiction, their distribution depends on $n$. So there is reason to believe that the maximum will also tend to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still not completely sure about your question setting but here's a shot:

For any $n$, the following are true:

- There are random variables $X_{i,n}$ for $i \in \{1,2,...,n\}$.
- Every $X_{i,n}$ is uniformly bounded and non-negative.
- $\forall i \neq j: X_{i,n}$ and $X_{j,n}$ are identically distributed, but not independent.
- $X_{i,n} = O_P(b_n)$ or in other words, ${X_{i,n} \over b_n}$ is probabilistically bounded for large enough $n$.

Am I correct above?  If so, your conjecture is false, with this counterexample:  For any $n$, imagine there are $n$ balls and you pick one of them uniformly at random, and $X_{i,n}$ is the indicator for picking the $i$th ball.  I.e., $X_{i,n} = 1$ with probabililty $1/n$ and $= 0$ otherwise.  These satisfy the first 3 bullets above.

For the 4th bullet, pick $b_n = 1/n$.  Then $X_{i,n}/b_n$ is either $n$ (with prob $1/n$) or $0$ (otherwise).  Thus $\forall \epsilon>0, \delta>0: \exists N: \forall n > N: Prob(X_{i,n}/b_n > \delta) < \epsilon$.

If these $X_{i,n}$ satisfy your prerequisites, then it is a counterexample because $\forall n: Y_n \equiv 1$ since exactly one of the $X_{i,n} = 1$.

== ADDENDUM ==

In fact, a slightly modified example shows that independence wouldn't help.  Consider $X_{i,n}$ binary with $Prob(X_{i,n} = 1) = 1/n$, and all the $X_{i,n}$ are independent.  You still have $Y_n = 0 \iff \forall i: X_{i,n} = 0$, and so $Prob(Y_n=0) = (1 - {1\over n})^n \approx {1 \over e}$ and $Prob(Y_n=1) \approx 1 - {1 \over e}$ and does not tend to $0$.

Comment: That's a nice counterexample, thank you.

Comment: you're welcome, and indeed "the devil is always in the details" :)